# WPF How to Create a DataTemplate Which has Canvas As Content By Code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have the data template defined by XAML as below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PointPushPinItemTemplate">
    <mapControl:MapItem mapControl:MapPanel.Location="{Binding}" >
        <Canvas>
            <Path StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Aqua">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </mapControl:MapItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use below code to create it, but failed:

```
private DataTemplate PushPinPointDataTemplate()
{
    var pointItemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(MapItem));
    pointItemFactory.SetValue(MapPanel.LocationProperty, new Binding());
    var pointCanvas = new Canvas();
    pointCanvas.Children.Add(new Path
    {
        StrokeThickness = 2.0,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow),
        Data = new EllipseGeometry {RadiusX = 3, RadiusY = 3}
    });

    //below line always throw exception that FrameworkElementFactory.SetValue can't set a visual value
    pointItemFactory.SetValue(MapItem.ContentProperty, pointCanvas);
    return new DataTemplate
    {
        DataType = typeof(Location),
        VisualTree = pointItemFactory
    };
}
```

How to achieve this? Previousely, I achieved this if there is no Canvas, but for this case, the Canvas to be the content of a content control.
ps: mapControl:MapItem is a UI element which inherited from ListBoxItem
mapControl:MapPanel.Location is a attached property

Comment: XAML and WPF/UWP are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can user other approaches, doing so misses 90% of the power and runs into problems every other piece. In MVVM you would just target that Template onto the ViewModel class it is there for. The existing code will figure out the rest. I wrote a intro into MVVM a few years back, it might help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create factories for the `Canvas` and the `Path` as well:

```
private DataTemplate PushPinPointDataTemplate()
{
    var pointItemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(MapItem));
    pointItemFactory.SetValue(MapPanel.LocationProperty, new Binding("."));

    var pathFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Path));
    pathFactory.SetValue(Path.StrokeThicknessProperty, 2.0);
    pathFactory.SetValue(Path.FillProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
    pathFactory.SetValue(Path.DataProperty, new EllipseGeometry { RadiusX = 3, RadiusY = 3 });

    var pointCanvasFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Canvas));
    pointCanvasFactory.AppendChild(pathFactory);

    pointItemFactory.AppendChild(pointCanvasFactory);
    return new DataTemplate
    {
        DataType = typeof(Location),
        VisualTree = pointItemFactory
    };
}
```

Note that using a `FrameworkElementFactory` is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx.

> The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a `string` or a memory stream using the `Load` method of the `XamlReader` class.